# export the value to the excel file and validating the excel output value to the defined value in katalon studio?

Tags: groovy, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

How to export the output value to the excel file and validating the excel output value to the defined value in katalon studio?

Comment: Hi, could you please post what have you tried before?

Answer (score 0):

@mahesht6923 - There is a great FREE Katalon Studio plugin to play around with Excel files. It's called Excel Keywords; you can have it from here:
https://store.katalon.com/product/34/Excel-Keywords

Sample code on how to use it is given here:
https://github.com/katalon-studio/katalon-excel-keyword

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

During a test I was able to pull a value off the webpage and insert it back into excel for a future test to use.  First I had to install the ExcelKeywords plugin and import it into the test script.

```
import com.kms.katalon.keyword.excel.ExcelKeywords as ExcelKeywords

//test was omitted ...    

//Parse the label to get the person id  name(id)
String nameAndId = WebUI.getText(findTestObject('Object Repository/Page_Person Profile (PP000)/label_lblPersonNameAndId'));
int startPosition = nameAndId.indexOf('(');
int endPosition = nameAndId.indexOf(')');

String personId =  nameAndId.substring(startPosition + 1, endPosition);

//Value stored in the excel file so I know where to put the personid
int rowNo = Integer.parseInt(gRowId);

String excelFilePath = "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Documents\\LearingTestData.xlsx";
String sheetName = "NEW_PERSON";
workbook01 = ExcelKeywords.getWorkbook(excelFilePath);
sheet01 = ExcelKeywords.getExcelSheet(workbook01, sheetName);
ExcelKeywords.setValueToCellByIndex(sheet01, rowNo, 0, personId);
ExcelKeywords.saveWorkbook(excelFilePath, workbook01);
```